# Cookie Consent blocking rest of JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I got this library from google, this cookie consent script. It works well but the problem is that untill you press the button and refresh the page the rest of javascripts won't work, so my navigation on phone isn't working neither the data-scroll animation. This is the code. I don't know where the problem is, if somebody could help me I would be thankful. Have a great day!

```
// --- Config --- //
var purecookieTitle = 'Cookies.'; // Title
var purecookieDesc =
  'Acest website folosește cookie-uri pentru a vă îmbunătăți experiența. Folosind site-ul nostru web, sunteți de acord cu toate cookie-urilor în conformitate cu politica noastră de confidențialitate.'; // Description
var purecookieLink =
  '<a href="politica-de-confidentialitate.html" target="_blank">Citesțe mai mult</a>'; // Cookiepolicy link
var purecookieButton = 'Am înțeles'; // Button text
// ---        --- //

function pureFadeIn(elem, display) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elem);
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  el.style.display = display || 'block';

  (function fade() {
    var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
    if (!((val += 0.02) > 1)) {
      el.style.opacity = val;
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  })();
}
function pureFadeOut(elem) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elem);
  el.style.opacity = 1;

  (function fade() {
    if ((el.style.opacity -= 0.02) < 0) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  })();
}

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires = '';
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + '=' + (value || '') + expires + '; path=/';
}
function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + '=';
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name + '=; Max-Age=-99999999;';
}

function cookieConsent() {
  if (!getCookie('purecookieDismiss')) {
    document.body.innerHTML +=
      '<div class="cookieConsentContainer" id="cookieConsentContainer"><div class="cookieTitle"><a>' +
      purecookieTitle +
      '</a></div><div class="cookieDesc"><p>' +
      purecookieDesc +
      ' ' +
      purecookieLink +
      '</p></div><div class="cookieButton"><a onClick="purecookieDismiss();">' +
      purecookieButton +
      '</a></div></div>';

    pureFadeIn('cookieConsentContainer');
  }
}

function purecookieDismiss() {
  setCookie('purecookieDismiss', '1', 14);
  pureFadeOut('cookieConsentContainer');
}

window.onload = function () {
  cookieConsent();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else stumble upon this issue, the problem is in this line:

```
document.body.innerHTML +=
```

If you replace it with this, for example, it works perfectly and does not block any other javascript, but obviously you have to add the id **footer** somewehere in your page

```
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML+=
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, put any `div` and assign an `id` to it:

```html
<div class="any" id="footer"></div>
```

...

In the JS file, in the `cookieConsent()` function, change
`document.body.innerHTML +=` to `document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML +=`.

The complete code would look like this:

```js
function cookieConsent() {
  if (!getCookie('purecookieDismiss')) {
    document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML +=
      '<div class="cookieConsentContainer" id="cookieConsentContainer"><div class="cookieTitle"><a>' +
      purecookieTitle +
      '</a></div><div class="cookieDesc"><p>' +
      purecookieDesc +
      '' +
      purecookieLink +
      '</p></div><div class="cookieButton"><a onClick="purecookieDismiss();">' +
      purecookieButton +
      '</a></div></div>';
    pureFadeIn('cookieConsentContainer');
  }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English ;(